# How to import a module with forRoot when using APP_INITIALIZER?

Tags: angular

I have a module that is responsible of querying my API through services, and I am planning to use that module in many apps. In turn, the apps are responsible of passing the configuration (e.g. API URL) to this module in the `forRoot` method:

```
export class APIModule {
  static forRoot(appConfig: AppConfig): ModuleWithProviders {
    return {
      ngModule: APIModule,
      providers: [
        services.ProductService,
        services.UserService,
        { provide: AppConfigToken, useValue: appConfig}
      ]
    };
  }
}
```

I'm facing a challenge because the apps (i.e. the client modules) get the configuration from a JSON file by leveraging `APP_INITIALIZER`. Here is the simplified definition:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    APIModule.forRoot({ apiUrl: '' }) // ISSUE HERE
  ],
  providers: [{
    provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
    multi: true,
    deps: [AppConfigService],
    useFactory: (appConfigService: AppConfigService) => {
      return () => {
        return appConfigService.getAppConfig();
      }
    }
  }],
})
export class AppModule { }
```

My question is: how could I call `APIModule.forRoot` from `useFactory`? Or in other words, how could I initialize `APIModule` from `useFactory`? I'm using `Angular7`.

Comment: Did you get any further with this? I'm facing the same issue.

Comment: Sorry, I don't remember and I'm not working on that project anymore.